# Category Entry and Exit Dates per ID AND Category

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table, where `ID` is the unique identifier. An can move from category to category, both up and down. My table records each day an `ID` stays in a given category. I am trying to identify the start date and the end date of an `ID` in a given category. The problem is that an `ID` can move up a category, and move back down to its original category after a certain number of days. Here is my table as an example with only `1 ID`:

```
ID      Category               Date

1            1              2021-01-01

1            1              2021-01-02

...

1           1              2021-01-24

1           2              2021-01-25

...

1          2               2021-02-15

1          1               2021-02-16

...

1         1               2021-04-20

1         2               2021-04-21
```

When I try to get the `MIN(DATE)` and `MAX(DATE)` and group by the category and `ID`, it shows me that the account was in `Category 1` from `2021-01-01` to `2021-04-20`, and in `Category 2` from `02-25` to `04-21`. I am trying to track the movements of the file in each bucket step by step, meaning in my ideal result, the movements of the account will be tracked as:

```
ID              Category        StartDate        EndDate

1                1              2021-01-01        2021-01-24

1               2               2021-01-25        2021-02-15

1               1               2021-02-16        2021-04-20

1               2               2021-04-21        NULL (or GETDATE())
```

How can I achieve this result? Any help would be appreciated. I tried using the `RANK()` function but because the table records every single day, it seems useless.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem that is most easily solved using the difference of row numbers:

```
select id, category, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, category order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by id, category, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Actually, the difference of row numbers is only simplest because you have not specified the database.  You can just subtract a sequence of numbers from the date to get a constant that defines each group.  That looks like:

```
select id, category, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, category order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, category, date - seqnum * interval '1 day';
```

However, the date arithmetic varies by database.